# Entity Framework foreign key error in two connect class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6.1

I use Entity Framework 6.1 in ASP.NET MVC.

My model is :

```
public class Article
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Article")]
    public virtual ICollection<FormulaItem> FormulaItem { get; set; }
}

public class FormulaItem
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdMaster")]
    public virtual Formula Formula { get; set; }
    public int IdMaster { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdArticle")]
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public int IdArticle { get; set; }

    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class Formula
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public FormulaMode Mode { get; set; }

    // Wen add this line I get error  
    //[ForeignKey("IdArticle")]        
    //public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    //public int? IdArticle { get; set; }               

    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<FormulaItem> Items { get; set; }

    public Formula()
    {
        Items = new List<FormulaItem>();
    }
}
```

This sample works fine, but when add the new poco:

```
    // When I add this line in class formula I get error  
    [ForeignKey("IdArticle")]        
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public int? IdArticle { get; set; }
```

to class `Formula` I get error:

> Formula_Items_Source_Formula_Items_Target: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical

Answer (score 0):

Consider using FluentAPI as it is more user-friendly:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<FormulaItem>()
        .HasOptional(b => b.Article )
        .WithMany(a => a.FormulaItem);
```

And in your case you must be missing another InverseProperty attribute:

```
[InverseProperty("FormulaItem")]
public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
```

Comment: hi
thank you for answer
I add your code but no work 
in top you can see error

Answer (score 0):

I add:

```
modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FormulaConfig());
public class FormulaConfig : EntityTypeConfiguration<Formula>
{
    public FormulaConfig()
    {               // one-to-many
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Article)
            .WithOptional(x=>x.Formula)         
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();

    }
}
```

but get error :

Article_Formula_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Article_Formula_Target' in relationship 'Article_Formula'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Comment: Well, it is a bit confusing... Decide what do you want to bind with. As i see one Article can be FK to many FormulaItems and one Formula can be FK to many FormulaItems. Do you need an article in the Formula then? You already have it in FormulaItem. And you building FK for formula...